# Configure method of SpringBootServletInitializer

Tags: spring-boot

I'm creating an Application with `SpringBootServletInitializer`. I'm unsure on how and when the configure method is called. I have placed a print statement in the method to check where it is called. However I do not find the print when I run the application. Am I making a silly mistake or have I fundamentally misunderstood how `SpringBootServletInitializer` works.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        builder.sources(DemoApplication.class);
        System.out.println("Called configure method");
        return builder;
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are running it as a java application the `configure` method will never be called. It will only be called when you are creating a war file and deploy that to a servlet container.

Comment: Will changing the `<packaging>` in my pom to `war` solve it?

Comment: Not if you keep running it as an executable jar... It will only get called if you deploy it to a servlet container.